# Django - createsuperuser IntegrityError

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

when i try to create superuser from shell or via manage.py or from Django-Admin page ; it throws error like :

```
IntegrityError at /admin/auth/user/add/
null value in column "link_karma" violates not-null constraint
```

Here is my models.py [User Part]:

```
class User_Profile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    link_karma = models.IntegerField()
    comment_karma = models.IntegerField()
    avatar = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def create_user_profile(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
        if created:
            User_Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

i added fallowing line in to settings.py:

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'accounts.User_Profile'
```

before add this line ;  it was the same.

**Note** : i tried to change type of link_karma field to CharField. it is same.

**Note** : If any additional data needed ; i can add it.

Comment: Fix the indents in your code. Btw, `User` already has email field.

Comment: I think, `create_user_profile` should be separate independant function, not `User_Profile` method.

Comment: what you mean independent function?

Comment: Not a part of `User_Profile` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `blank=True, null=True` for both `link_karma` and `comment_karma`. You're not passing any values to those fields so when your create statement tries to create the object, it doesn't know what to give `link_karm` hence the error.

As goliney correctly pointed out, you dont need email in your User_Profile model as User already has it.

Comment: didnt know that i have to set something for IntegerField.thank you.